# Microsoft Edge not immediately redrawing element after class change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

On my React site, I have a profile/account dropdown (similar to Github's, where you click on your profile picture and a dropdown appears). On most browsers, it works correctly. When the `div` is clicked, it applies the `dropdown--active` class to itself. This `dropdown--active` class contains a rule for the child element, `dropdown__content`, to change its `display` from `none` to `block`, thereby toggling the display of the dropdown content on click.

Before click:

```
<div class="dropdown account-dropdown">
  <a href="/#" class="dropdown__trigger ">
    <span class="account-dropdown--name">admin</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown__content">
    <div class="account-dropdown--identity account-dropdown--segment">
      Signed in as admin
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After click:

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown--active account-dropdown">
  <a href="/#" class="dropdown__trigger ">
    <span class="account-dropdown--name">admin</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown__content">
    <div class="account-dropdown--identity account-dropdown--segment">
      Signed in as admin
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the only way I can get it to display in Microsoft Edge is to click some where else on the screen **after** I've already clicked the parent element. With Inspect Element open, I can tell that the class is in fact being applied immediately after click, but the child element is not redrawn/reevaluated until some where else on the screen is clicked. Alternatively, tabbing to the element and clicking "enter" does not cause this problem.

Works in Chrome, IE 11, Firefox fine though.

Comment: Do you have any css like `:focus`, `:active`, `:hover`, `:visited`? It's probably conflicting with `.dropdown--active` on Edge.

Comment: @falsarella I don't think so. I ended up changing it so that the element is destroyed and recreated on click to get around the issue.